# PDAL removes color attribute from LiDAR point cloud?

Tags: lidar, las, point-cloud, pdal

I am trying pdal to perform a ground filtering on a point cloud (las file) with colors. I use the pcl option and this tutorial [Identifying ground returns using ProgressiveMorphologicalFilter segmentation](http://www.pdal.io/tutorial/pcl_ground.html#pcl-ground)

```
pdal pcl -i input.las -o output.las -p sor-pmf.json --visualize -v4
```

However, the result I get is without colors. How can I prevent this from happening? I tried pdal info and there are no RGB values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the PMF filter that has been fixed in newer versions of PDAL that was causing this. Try PDAL 1.1+ to get past this issue. If you still have trouble, please ask on the [mailing list](http://www.pdal.io/community.html#mailing-list).